# Greenplum Spark Connector org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error when writing data to gpfdist

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, greenplum

I've a Greenplum cluster on Azure that I'm trying to connect to with spark from my local machine (using Pivotal Greenplum Spark Connector).

I'm doing something like this in my scala code:

```scala
var options = Map[String, String]()
options += ("url" -> url)
options += ("user" -> credential("user"))
options += ("password" -> credential("password"))
options += ("partitionColumn" -> partitionColumn)

sqlContext.read.format("greenplum").options(options).load()
```

For testing purpose, I've created a user :

```sql
DROP USER IF EXISTS user1;
CREATE USER user1 CREATEEXTTABLE (type='writable') PASSWORD 'p@ss0rd';
```

Then used this user to create a databse/table as follows

```
drop table if exists sample;
create table public.sample (id serial, big bigint, wee smallint, stuff text) distributed by (id) ;
insert into sample (big) values (generate_series(1,100));
update sample set wee = 0; 
update sample set wee = 1 where mod(id,7)=1;
update sample set stuff = substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',1,mod(wee,13));
```

Now when I execute my spark code with Greenplum credentials, it seems (when running in debug mode) that the code is successfully reading table metadata (it fetches the columns and types), but reading rows fails with `SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)`. Here is the stacktrace:

```
2020-03-24 19:04:31,168 WARN [Executor task launch worker for task 0] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@14fab679 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error when writing data to gpfdist http://127.0.0.1:60352/spark_e0aa1f0c8646f023_fffec8bf08e0054d_driver_261, quit after 8 tries  (seg1 172.21.0.4:6001 pid=25909)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:318)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:294)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:120)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$$anonfun$2.apply(Jdbc.scala:81)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$$anonfun$2.apply(Jdbc.scala:79)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource$$anonfun$5.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
    at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:26)
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:50)
    at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource$$anonfun$tried$1.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at resource.DeferredExtractableManagedResource.tried(AbstractManagedResource.scala:33)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.copyTable(Jdbc.scala:83)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.liftedTree1$1(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:105)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:104)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to open ports on the Greenplum cluster on Azure but that didn;t help
[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The Spark connector launches a gpfdist server on each Spark worker node, determines the address/hostname of the machine where the worker runs and reports it to Greenplum so that Greenplum can send data to it. In your case this resolved to 127.0.0.1 as you're running on a local machine and Greenplum on Azure failed to connect to gpfdist server on http://127.0.0.1:60352

For this to work, your Spark workers have to be accessible from Azure via a routable IP address or DNS resolvable hostname. You can specify whether to use a hostname or IP address (and which network interface to use to get the IP address) by specifying options described here: https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/1-6/using_the_connector.html#addrcfg

Answer (score 1):

As @denalex mentioned in his answer, running spark from your local machine may not be the easiest because Greenplum won't know where to send the data.

Another approach would be to spin up a Spark cluster or host on Azure, and make it visible to Greenplum on the same network.

Comment: thanks @oliveralbertini, I am afraid I cannot have Greenplum on my network, cause I don't own the DB, and similarly cannot expose the spark cluster. What do you recommend alternatively, will using a simple JDBC Driver work with Spark?

Comment: @bachr I would try creating a Spark cluster somewhere on the cloud (Azure, AWS, GCP, etc.) and use network rules to allow traffic from the Greenplum hosts.

Comment: I;ve endup using the Greenplum JDBC driver with Spark SQL. I had some issues due to pgBouncer but so far it's working OK. Still need to investigate performance of reading/writing few GBs of data.